# Protractor: Updating baseURL so not running on "app/index"

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is it possible to run Protractor tests without the directory extension "app/index.html" being added?
I would like to run the test through MAMP localhost:8888/project/ but without the APP directory used to serve the static files. Updating the base URL to

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/project',
```

will then try and run the application on  `"http://localhost:8888/project/app/index.html"`

Answer (score 0):

Solution was in the Jasmine test file, this was causing the problem

```
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.get('app/index');
});
```